# ld cannot find existing library in a build context

Tags: gcc, ld, libtool

My build fails with a list of missing libraries:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lusb
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lftdi1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
```

However, for each of these libraries when I run

> ld -llib --verbose

I can see that the library is located. For example:

> ld -lftdi1 --verbose

```
[...]
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libftdi1.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib64/libftdi1.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libftdi1.so succeeded
-lftdi1 (/usr/lib/libftdi1.so)
libusb-1.0.so.0 needed by /usr/lib/libftdi1.so
found libusb-1.0.so.0 at /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
libc.so.6 needed by /usr/lib/libftdi1.so
found libc.so.6 at /usr/lib/libc.so.6
libudev.so.1 needed by /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
found libudev.so.1 at /usr/lib/libudev.so.1
libpthread.so.0 needed by /usr/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
found libpthread.so.0 at /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /usr/lib/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libcap.so.2 needed by /usr/lib/libudev.so.1
found libcap.so.2 at /usr/lib/libcap.so.2
librt.so.1 needed by /usr/lib/libudev.so.1
found librt.so.1 at /usr/lib/librt.so.1
libm.so.6 needed by /usr/lib/libudev.so.1
found libm.so.6 at /usr/lib/libm.so.6
libresolv.so.2 needed by /usr/lib/libudev.so.1
found libresolv.so.2 at /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

The build line that fails is this one:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -Wno-pointer-sign -g -O2 --static   -o myprog myprog-main.o myprog-term.o ./libmyprog.a -lusb-1.0 -lusb -lftdi1   -lelf -lpthread -lm -lreadline -lncurses
```

What might be the cause of the failure?

Comment: You're static linking, looks like you need `.a` (static) libraries, not `.so` (dynamic).

Comment: @Mat It doesn't complain about -lelf, and I can see ld finding libelf as /usr/lib/libelf.so